# Dynamic output issue when rowset is empty

Tags: u-sql

I'm running a u-sql script similar to this:

```
@output =
SELECT Tag,
       Json
FROM @table;

OUTPUT @output
TO @"/Dir/{Tag}/filename.txt"
USING Outputters.Text(quoting : false);
```

The problem is that *@output* is empty and the execution crashes. I already checked that if I don't use *{tag}* in the output path the script works well (it writes an empty file but that's the expectable).

Is there a way to avoid the crash and simply don't output anything?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add criteria as a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` which ensure the output files are not empty?

Comment: No @wBob, in this scenario I can't..

Answer (score 1):

The form you are using is not yet publicly supported. [Output to Files (U-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/output-to-files-u-sql) documents the only supported version right now.

That said, depending on the runtime that you are using, and the flags that you have set in the script, you might be running the private preview feature of outputting to a set of files. In that case, I would expect that it would work properly.

Are you able to share a job link?

Comment: user3015868/Adrian (can you please give yourself a real name? :)) is correct that this feature is currently only available in a private preview. There is currently a known issue with having an empty rowset on the output that leads to this crash. The team is working on a fix, though I cannot provide an ETA yet. Please send the job link to usql at microsoft dot com if you don't feel comfortable sharing it publicly.